# strange Java generics compilation error: parameterized method is not applicable for same parameterized types?

Tags: java, generics

I've stumbled across this error and I can't find the problem:

```
The method compute(Set<String>, Set<String>) 
in the type JaccardSimilarity<String> is not applicable 
for the arguments (Set<String>, Set<String>)
```

The method in question is using Generics:

```
public class JaccardSimilarity<E> implements SimilarityMeasure<Set<E>, Set<E>> {

    @Override
    public double compute(Set<E> s1, Set<E> s2){
        // compute some stuff
    return unionSize == 0 ? 1 : intersectionSize / (double)unionSize;
    }
}
```

I'm calling it in my class this way:

```
public MyClass {
    private JaccardSimilarity<String> sim = new JaccardSimilarity<String>();

    public void calc() {
    Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<>();
    s1.add("hallo welt");
    Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<>();
    s2.add("hallo welt");
            // the line below throws the error..
    double result = sim.compute(s1, s2);
    }
```

In my humble understanding of Java Generics this is perfectly valid code...

How is this possible?

Edit - Additional Code:

```
public interface SimilarityMeasure<Q, R> extends RelevanceFunction<Q, R> {}
```

and..

```
public interface RelevanceFunction<Q, R> {
    public double compute(Q v1, R v2);
}
```

Edit 2: Here are the Imports:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;

import <redacted>.JaccardSimilarity;
```

Edit 3: This was the error:

```
import <redacted>.representation.Set;
```

subtle...

Comment: Could you provide a minimal complete example that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Your import statements might be relevant.

Comment: added all other relevant classes and import statements. I'm not sure how to construct a single file example with abstract classes and interfaces. But with putting the code in sperate Files it should work.

Comment: please add the imports in JaccardSimilarity - that is the last place the import error could be

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might be importing different classes. Either for `Set` or `String`.

Double-check your imports!

Also consider using `Set<? extends E>` in your implementation. Then `E` only needs to be a supertype of the actual type you use, if it satisfies the other requirements.

Comment: Thanks, this helped - but shouldn't it work when the other imported Set is defined as this: `public class Set<E> extends Representation
implements Iterable<E>, java.util.Set<E> {`

Comment: From the answer: consider using `Set<? extends E>` - I'd also highly recommend renaming your class to not name-shadow a common java util class.

Comment: Avoid overloading class names such as `Set` - they are bound to cause confusion such as this. Assuming that you had the wrong `Set` in `JaccardSimilarity`, `HashSet` probably does *not* implement the other `Set`.

Comment: Oh well, It's not my code. Learned my lesson in regards to imports and Eclipse... Thanks again!